# Matriculate! Is it possible to forbit to matriculate?

Tags: meaning

I think that TO APPLE and TO MATRICULATE are two different actions. I think it's possible to forbid someone to apply to a University. But is it possible to forbid to matriculate? I understand MATRICUALTE as a process which doesn't involve only one part which is an applicant. What do you think? Is it logical to say "to forbid someone to matriculate"?

Comment: Presumably you  mean _apply_ and not _apple_! _Matriculate_ is defined as _be enrolled at a college or university_, so, yes, a college can refuse to accept someone as a student.

Comment: Kate! I mean a bit different thing. Can for example a mother forbid her son to matriculate?

Comment: _Matriculate_ is a rather technical word which normally refers to the official process for admitting students. We might speak of a mother forbidding her son to go to university (though it seems an unlikely scenario), but we wouldn't use the word _matriculate_.

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically it is equally acceptable to say "We forbid you to apply to university" and "We forbid you to matriculate at this university".

However the word "matriculate" is quite rare and technical.  The meaning is "complete the formal process of enrollment at a university".  It is often used to mean "pass the entrance tests for the university", but there would be other requirements.

Whether a mother can forbid something is more of an interpersonal or legal question than a English language question.  You wouldn't say "She forbid her son to matriclate at the university".  But you could say:

> She forbid her son to go to university.

> She didn't allow her son to enroll at university.

> She didn't let her son study at university.

It would be rather rare.  Most mothers would be proud of their son going to university. And, of course if this is in the UK, her son would be an adult, so legally she can't forbid him from doing anything.